# Which firebase databases should I use for a Realtime voting platform?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have a project where anonymous people can vote up or down a sentence, since I'm using Firebase Auth for anon auth, should I use `Firestore` or the `Realtime Database`?

Comment: Since recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, I recommend (pun intended) taking the [database recommender](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore) in the documentation. As Hooshyar answered below, I'd expect that to point to Realtime Database given the frequency of (small) writes.

Comment: Thanks, [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen), Great Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore), an app with frequent read and writes is better to use the real-time database, since using Firestore you'll get charged by the amount of read and write you do.

Comment: Thanks [Hooshyar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10622449/hooshyar), as you and Frank suggested I decided to go with the Realtime Database,I'll make sure to let you know about the results.